# Symfony2 looped html input text box to symfony form type

Tags: php, symfony

Anyone know ways of how to turn something like this into a formType?

```
{% for something in somethingTable %}
<input type="text" value="{{something.input}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

The code above displays all records from the database in a textbox, but I would like to know if there is a way to turn this into a symfony formtype.
so the output would be instead of an **input type = "text"** it would be something like this? **{{form_start(form)}} {{form_end(form)}}**

Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhmm, it's hard to guess what you're exactly expecting, but maybe `CollectionType`?

Comment: To turn your code into a form, you can just surround it with `<form></form>`. But this is probably not what you're looking for. Please explain what u're trying to achieve, your post doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? If you have data from a table as default values you can load them easily while creating a form with Symfony components.

Comment: You have to create a form type depending on yours entities and relationships inside them

Comment: The reason for trying to convert it to a form is that I would like it to be able to be submitted so that it would go to an action in the controller. say for example it displays "male" from the database and I would like to change it to "female", I would change the "male" to "female" then submit, which in turn should change the data stored in the database to "female". @insertusernamehere

Comment: I guess this is the right starting point: [The Symfony Cookbook: Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html).

Comment: I have tried something similar with a dropdown with a one to many relationship but I don't know how to use it in an input form @DOZ